# Duplicate 'DisplayFormat' Attribute in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, displayformat

I would like to display a value from ViewModel in the view. If value is null, it will be displayed as "--", otherwise it will be rounded to 2 decimal places. The following code in my ViewModel gave me "Duplicate DisplayFormat Attribute" error.

```
[Display(Name = "Number")]
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText = "--")]
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false, DataFormatString = "{0:n2}")]
public Nullable<float> C_Targets { get; set; }
```

I was wondering if there is a way that I can combine these two cases in one displayformat attribute? Thanks!

Comment: Just use `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}, NullDisplayText = "--")]` The `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I also have a followup question. What if I would like to display the number in 2 decimal format if it is less than 1 while in integer format if is larger than 1? Maybe in this case it is not doable anymore to use DisplayFormat only? I guess I have to handle this case in the controller.

Comment: No its no possible using `[DisplayFormat]`

Comment: Use String.Format instead of DisplayFormat to display number format based on certain condition. So far it is impossible to use DisplayFormat for dynamic value formatting with if/switch statement.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks! But the LINQ statement in the controller cannot recognize String.Format. I know I may use AsEnumerable(), etc. to do it but it makes code less cleaner compared to dealing this situation in the ViewModel. That's why I asked this question. Thanks for your advice again!